# When deleting records from mongoDB, elastics is not syncing with it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Somebody please tell me why aren't syncing my mogoosastic and mongodb?
When I delete records from mongoDB, records still are seen, until the server is restarted.  this is me search function

```
exports.search = function (req, res) {
  if (!req.query.q) return res.status(400).send('No Query Provided')
  log.error(req.query.q)

  var query = {
    query_string: {
      filtered: {
        query: {
          multi_match: {query: req.query.q,}
        },
        filter: {term: {isDeleted: false}
        }
      }
    }
  }

  User.search(query, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return handleError1(res, err)
    var ret = _.map(results.hits.hits, result => ({
      userID: result._id,
      _score: result._score,
      name: result._source.name,
      loc: result._source.loc,
      info: result._source.info,
      images: result._source.images,
    }))
    return res.send(ret)
  })
}
```

And this one is my Schema declaration

```
isDeleted: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false, es_indexed: true}
```

what is wrong with this code...

Comment: How are you deleting documents? pls provide the code of deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line of code and everything was ok

```
.then(groups => {
      return User.findById(uid).exec()
    })
    .then(user => {
      let email = user.credentials.loginEmail + '_' + moment().format('YYYYMMDDEHHmmss')
      if(app.get('env') === 'localtest') {
        email = user.credentials.loginEmail + '_deleted'
      }
      user.credentials.loginEmail = email;
      user.isDeleted = true;
      user.updated.at = new Date();
      user.save()
        .then(user_ =>{
          user.sendInfoUpdate()
          return res.status(204).send()
        })
        .catch(err => {
          return handleError(res, err)
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return handleError(res, err)
    })
```